# TicTacToe - How do i stop the game if theres a winner,

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

So this is how the program will received the data

```
 x_data = []
    def xuser_input():
        while True:
            x = As("Player X, Please enter a number to place: ",int)
            if (x > 10) or (x < 0):
                print("Input must be Bigger than 0 and Smaller than 9")
                continue
            try:
                board[x] = "X"
                x_data.append(x)
            except (IndexError):
                print("Invalid input")
                continue
            t_Board()
            break
```

There will be another for Y as well.
This is the tictactoe board

```
def t_Board():
    print(f"| {board[0]} | {board[1]} | {board[2]} |\n_____________")
    print(f"| {board[3]} | {board[4]} | {board[5]} |\n_____________")
    print(f"| {board[6]} | {board[7]} | {board[8]} |")
```

This will stop the game if this condition is met which is the wining formula.

```
    def stops_board():
        if (board[0] == board[1] == board[2]) or (board[3] == board[4] == board[5]) or (
        board[6] == board[7] == board[8]) or (board[0] == board[3] == board[6]) or (
        board[1] == board[4] == board[7]) or (board[2] == board[5] == board[8]) or (
        board[0] == board[4] == 
        board[8]) or (board[2] == board[4] == board[6]):
            return False
```

For now this is how i ask the data input and check if theres a winning solution

```
 while True:
        xuser_input()
        stops_board()
        yuser_input()
        stops_board()
```

Comment: Have you tried break?

Comment: you have to call `stops_board()` from `xuser_input()` after user entering the input

Comment: Broadly speaking, you perform an early stop to a function by adding a `return` statement, and  you do the same to a for/while loop by adding a `break` statement.

Comment: i tried break in the function stops_board but it couldt work as there is no while loop in there

Comment: oh yea i should put the call stops_board inside of the xuser_input lemme try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i see it, `stops_board()` should return True if the game should stop, and False if it should continue. correct? if so, you could use:

```
 while True:
        xuser_input()
        if stops_board(): break
        yuser_input()
        if stops_board(): break
```

Comment: wait no it will stop the game and return False if the winning solution (stops_board) is met and so will stop the While True loop. At least thats what i though and could't work. But your suggestion looks like it could work lemme give it a try

Comment: ohh i just got it, you were right , so i change the return False in stops_board to return True hence, making the break statement work and so it worked

Answer (score 1):

You should first figure out the steps:

1. Initialise the board( set board list, players' name, players' sign( X or O ) randomly
2. Set a while loop and perform the following
3. Ask player for a valid position
4. Check if position is valid or not
5. Set the board index to the player's sign
6. Check if the player has won and break the loop
7. Check if the board is filled and it is a tie and break if true
8. Change player and go to step 3

[Function to initialise board, check valid postition and draw the board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxEUc.png)

[check if there is a winner or it is a draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJL5F.png)

[The gameplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3t3X.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
def stops_board():
    if (board[0] == board[1] == board[2]) or (board[3] == board[4] == board[5]) or (
    board[6] == board[7] == board[8]) or (board[0] == board[3] == board[6]) or (
    board[1] == board[4] == board[7]) or (board[2] == board[5] == board[8]) or (
    board[0] == board[4] == board[8]) or (board[2] == board[4] == board[6]):
        return True



 while True:
        xuser_input()
        if stops_board(): break
        yuser_input()
        if stops_board(): break
```